# Proving the relation $\frac 1 2 \left[\nabla^2,r \right] = \frac 1 r + \frac \partial {\partial r}$ (quantum mechanics exercise)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, vectors, differentiation, commutator

I'm trying to prove this relation in my quantum mechanics exercise book

$$\frac 1 2 \left[\nabla^2,r \right] = \frac 1 r + \frac \partial {\partial r}.$$

Here's my attempt:

1. Expand the Laplacian operator
   $$\frac 1 2 \left[\nabla^2,r \right] =\frac 1 2\left\{\nabla\cdot[\nabla,r]+[\nabla,r]\cdot \nabla\right\}$$
2. Calculate $[\nabla,r]=\frac{\vec r}{r}$, then I have
   $$\frac 1 2\left\{\nabla\cdot[\nabla,r]+[\nabla,r]\cdot \nabla\right\}=\frac 1 2\left\{\nabla\cdot\frac{\vec r}{r}+\frac{\vec r}{r}\cdot \nabla\right\}$$
3. I'm stuck in this step, the solution manual suggests that
   $$\frac 1 2\left\{\nabla\cdot\frac{\vec r}{r}+\frac{\vec r}{r}\cdot \nabla\right\}=\frac 1 2 \left[2\frac{\vec r}{r}\cdot \nabla\right]+\frac 1 2\left(\nabla \cdot \frac{\vec r}{r}\right)=\frac 1 r + \frac \partial {\partial r}\tag{1}$$
   I don't see why (1) is true, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\nabla$ in $\nabla\cdot [\nabla, r]$ acts not only
on the commutator, but also the test function
$$
\nabla\cdot [\nabla, r] f = \nabla\cdot \frac{\vec{r}}{r} f = 
\Big(\frac{2}{r} + \frac{\vec{r}}{r}\cdot \nabla\Big)f
$$